# How google guice works internally

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection, guice

I was going through the google `guice` and then i thought about how it might be working.

So This is my theory on how `property injector` might be working.

`Guice` first wants us to create a `injector` and pass all the `binding` information to it.

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new BillingModule());
```

*code snippets from [google guice page](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted)

OK at this point i can think that there is a class with all the information of `binding`.

and when we do

```
injector.getInstance(RealBillingService.class);
```

Here we do the trick.

`injector` will return a `proxy instance` for the real `RealBillingService` object and when we call a

method of `RealBillingService` object, `proxy instance` invocation handler uses `reflection` to

figure out the properties to inject and fullfill it based on the information passed during the creation of injector.

**QUESTION**

This is the way i suppose, the `guice` works. If i am wrong, what would be the actual way by which `'Guice'` achieve it ?

If this is the way `guice` work then `Guice` always returns the `proxy object` and the user code always makes call on the `proxy objects`. is this true ?

---

Pictorial representation on my explaination

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your understanding is a little off.  Think of it this way: when you do `Guice.createInjector(...)`, *that's* when Guice does all the reflection to figure out what depends on what and what needs to get injected where.  When you do `injector.getInstance(...)`, Guice doesn't need to do any reflection.  It creates the `RealBillingService` right then, injecting all its (transitive) dependencies, and returns that (not a proxy).

If you use Guice's AOP functionality then those objects will be proxies, but otherwise Guice doesn't return proxies.  It simply invokes the `@Inject` constructor, sets the `@Inject`-annotated fields, calls the `@Inject`-annotated methods, and returns that object.

EDIT: See also [MiniGuice](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/extensions/mini/src/com/google/inject/mini/MiniGuice.java), a single-class implementation of a Guice-like injector.